# need sum of value based on category

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sum

Table have data like

```
<--------------------------->  
no      category     value 
<--------------------------->      
1        1           2000    
2        1           1000     
3        2            500    
4        3           3000    
5        1           2000   
6        2           -500        
7        3           5000    
8        1          -1000
```

And i want output like

```
<----------------------------------> 
no  category     amount       Sum   
<---------------------------------->   
1        1       2000         2000                
2        1       1000         3000                 
3        2        500          500                 
4        3       3000         3000                 
5        1       2000         5000                  
6        2       -500            0                 
7        3       5000         8000
8        1      -1000         4000
```

for eg: take `category=1`
so,

```
no:1
amount=2000--->total=2000
no:2
amount=1000---->total=3000
no:5
amount=2000---->total=5000
no:8
amount=-1000---->total=4000
```

that means sum of each category on every row
and with better performance

Comment: Show your efforts please.

Comment: and define *"better performance"*

Comment: i need the code @Dukeling

Comment: [This article explains how to calculate running total](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is calculating rolling total.
The fastest way in SQL Server 2005 / 2008 / 2008 R2 I know is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744550/1744834. You have to have unique secuential column inside each category to use this method, like this:

```
create table #t (no int, category int, value int, id int, primary key (category, id))

insert into #t (no, category, value, id)
select no, category, value, row_number() over (partition by category order by no)
from test

;with 
CTE_RunningTotal
as
(
    select T.no, T.category, T.value, cast(T.value as decimal(29, 10)) as total_value, T.id
    from #t as T
    where T.id = 1
    union all
    select T.no, T.category, T.value, cast(T.value + C.total_value as decimal(29, 10)) as total_value, T.id
    from CTE_RunningTotal as C
        inner join #t as T on T.id = C.id + 1 and T.category = C.category
)
select C.no, C.category, C.value, C.value
from CTE_RunningTotal as C
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/010d1/3)

you could also use shorter query, but performance is worse (I think it's O(N^2) vs O(N) for recursive CTE):

```
select t1.no, t1.category, t1.value, sum(t2.value)
from test as t1
    inner join test as t2 on t2.category = t1.category and t2.no <= t1.no
group by t1.no, t1.category, t1.value
order by t1.no
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/010d1/6)

Comment: this working in sql server 2005? @RomanPekar

Comment: yes it should work in SQL Server 2005

Comment: `Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "total_value" of recursive query "CTE_RunningTotal"`
this is the error i got

Comment: you probable have decimal type for value column?

Comment: why the above code not work with decimal value?

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx - type of sum could be not equal type of numbers you're adding together

Answer (score 0):

You need to self-join both tables with row numbers:

```
;WITH t(No,Category,value,row) AS
(
    SELECT No, category, value
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by category ORDER BY no) AS row
   FROM Table1
)
SELECT t1.No, t1.category, t1.value, sum(t2.value) as sums
  FROM t t1
  JOIN t t2
    ON t1.row >= t2.row
   AND t1.Category = t2.Category
 GROUP BY t1.No, t1.category, t1.value;
```

Output:

```
| NO | CATEGORY | VALUE | SUMS |
--------------------------------
|  1 |        1 |  2000 | 2000 |
|  2 |        1 |  1000 | 3000 |
|  3 |        2 |   500 |  500 |
|  4 |        3 |  3000 | 3000 |
|  5 |        1 |  2000 | 5000 |
|  6 |        2 |  -500 |    0 |
|  7 |        3 |  5000 | 8000 |
|  8 |        1 | -1000 | 4000 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abc4d/20)

Comment: its take `00:00:02` execution time....its really slow @himso56

Comment: @user2633770 - I don't think there should be any faster way than this. Looking at [the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abc4d/20), it takes about 1 to 3 ms only.

Comment: i have 8000 and counting records

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following sql functions [SQL functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) it shows you how to use it and how to apply it

Comment: This should be a comment. Also the OP wants it for SQL Server not for MySQL.